# Where can some worked problems in classical mechanics (and more specifically the Lagrangian and Hamiltonian formalisms) be found?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, resource-recommendations, hamiltonian-formalism, education

I've been looking for a textbook in classical mechanics that's readily available (like can be found in the library of James Cook University of Townsville, Australia) and full of fully-answered questions in the Lagrangian/Hamiltonian formalisms yet I can't find any. My first port of call was the Schaum's Outlines and Demystified series but the only member of these series I could find that was relevant was [Lagrangian Dynamics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0070692580) which is difficult for me to track-down in real-life.

It would be particularly helpful if one could point me to a free eBook with this material.

Comment: I always liked Classical Mechanics by R. Douglas Gregory which I've seen in two different uni libraries.

Comment: Only questions and answers:  http://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0605057

Comment: Best book for such stuffs is [HERE](http://www.amazon.com/Classical-Dynamics-A-Contemporary-Approach/dp/0521636361)

Comment: Hi Brenton Horne, Phys.SE only allows a limited number of resource recommendation questions, because they tend to be e.g. _primarily opinion-based_ and list-questions. I'm closing this a _duplicate,_ not because it is an exact duplicate, but to point in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

John R. Taylor's Classical Mechanics has a couple of chapters on Lagrange and Hamilton that I found very helpful.

Comment: AFAICT, such PDFs violate [American Piracy Laws](http://www.riaa.com/physicalpiracy.php?content_selector=piracy_online_the_law) (even though OP is in Australia, SE is an American company).

Comment: @KyleKanos Is that so? I have had professors direct me to just look for a pdf online rather than going to the library.

Comment: Either your professors are ignorant of the law or they just don't care. Either way, that would not prevent you from being sued for piracy.